# Is this crashing error my fault, or game-centers

Tags: swift, game-center

So I am a very new developer, just launched my app today for the first time!  SO HAPPY!

Anyway I am having the most peculiar crash I cant quite figure out.  For some reason out of the 30 ish downloads of the app today 13 of them have had this crash, exactly one time.  For some reason this only happens once, it would seem to be only the first time the player is on the death scene.  I cant find a correlation in device, OS, or anything just sorta random.

Here is the crashalytics report : [here](http://crashes.to/s/bd6f97760af)

Anyway below is the code that is happening I have commented the line where crashalytics thinks the error is happen

```
func saveHighscore(score:Int) -> Int
    {
        //authenticateLocalPlayer()
        var temp:Int = -99
        //var save:Int = -99
        //check if user is signed in
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated
        {

            var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "TerribleToothacheSP99") //leaderboard id here
            scoreReporter.value = Int64(lscore) //score variable here (same as above)
            var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

            //save = scoreReporter.rank
            GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    //println("error")
                }


            })

            temp = lbread()
            //temp = scoreReporter.rank

        }
        //return save
        return temp
    }


var ttoout:Int = -99
    func lbread() -> Int
    {
        var toout:Int = -99
        let leaderBoardRequest = GKLeaderboard()
        leaderBoardRequest.identifier = "TerribleToothacheSP99"

        leaderBoardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler { (scores, error) -> Void in
            //println("STUFF")
            if (error != nil) {
                //println("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                self.ttoout = -99
            } else if (scores != nil) {
                let localPlayerScore = leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore
                //println("Local player's score: \(localPlayerScore.rank)")
                toout = localPlayerScore.rank
                self.ttoout = localPlayerScore.rank
            }
            self.recievedScore() //Line 1017  THE CRASH HAPPENS HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
        return toout
    }


func recievedScore()
    {
        if (ttoout == -99)
        {
            reportext2.text = "Go Online To See Global Ranking"
            makeTextInOneLine(reportext2, size: width / 1.2)
        }
        else
        {
            //ttoout = 99999999
            reportext2.text = "Global Ranking: " + String(ttoout)
            makeTextInOneLine(reportext2, size: width / 1.2)
        }
    }

func makeTextInOneLine(text: SKLabelNodePlus, size: CGFloat) // I am using SKLabelNode+ by maxKargin
    {
        //println(text.text)

        text.drawLabel()
        while(text.texture?.size().width > size)
        {
            text.fontSize -= 1

            text.drawLabel()

        }

        text.drawLabel()
    }
```

If you have any questions about why I do something, or what a variable means dont hesitate to ask.  Thank you so much for looking this over!

This is some extra code, including what calls lbread.  It is probably not necessary to the error so you probably dont need to read it.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){

    rnk = saveHighscore(lscore.self)
        if (GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated == true)
        {
            reportext2.text = "Waiting for data from scoreboard"
            makeTextInOneLine(reportext2, size: width / 1.2)
        }
        else
        {
            reportext2.text = "Login to GameCenter to see ranking"
            makeTextInOneLine(reportext2, size: width / 1.2)
        }

        var phs = defaults.integerForKey("THighScore")
        if (lscore.self > defaults.integerForKey("THighScore"))
        {
            //Current score is better then past one
            defaults.setInteger(lscore.self, forKey: "THighScore")
            hasover = true
        }
        else
        {
            //Past score is still reigning champ
        }
        saveHighscore2(defaults.integerForKey("THighScore"))

    }

func saveHighscore2(score:Int)
    {
        //authenticateLocalPlayer()
        var temp:Int = -99
        //var save:Int = -99
        //check if user is signed in
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated
        {

            var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "TerribleToothacheSP99") //leaderboard id here
            scoreReporter.value = Int64(lscore) //score variable here (same as above)
            var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

            //save = scoreReporter.rank
            GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    //println("error")
                }


            })

            //temp = lbread()
            //temp = scoreReporter.rank

        }
        //return save
        //return temp
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your app!

A quick answer will be that you should do your UI updates in the main thread

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())
{
    //do UI updates here
    self.recievedScore() 
}
```